# SQL Server extra text after table name in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I found a SQL statement to the effect of:

```
SELECT * FROM Users x
```

My question is: what is `x`? I have never seen this before.

Thanks.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that the Readability gain is very much overrated. It's handy if you are writing short term queries, such as during an investigation, but I would recommend not using aliases in permanent code. If someone comes along to maintain the code at a later date they will not know whether C.ID refers to Customer.ID, Currency.ID or CostCode.ID. Whereas if the full table name is given it's clearer what data is being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an alias. The `AS` keyword is optional and has been left out, but it is the same as:

```
SELECT * FROM Users AS x
```

This means you can (in some implementations of SQL, SQL Server being one of them, *must*) use `x` in the rest of the query to refer back to the table `Users` specified here. For example:

```
SELECT x.MyColumn
FROM Users x
WHERE x.AnotherColumn = 42
```

There are three general use cases for aliases:

1. Readability. For long table names or when the name will be used many times, it can improve readability. For example, imagine the following without the alias:

   ```
   SELECT x.SomeColumn, x.SomeOtherColumn, x.AThirdColumn
   FROM [my crAzy Table Name with spaces in it] x
   WHERE x.AnotherColumn = 42
   ```
2. Disambiguation. Often used for self-joins, note the use of the same table twice. You must use an alias to differentiate the two instances of the `Users` table:

   ```
   SELECT x.SomeColumn, COUNT(y.SomeColumn)
   FROM Users x
   INNER JOIN Users y ON x.SomeOtherColumn < y.SomeOtherColumn
   GROUP BY x.SomeColumn
   ```
3. Sub-queries in a FROM or JOIN clause (also called derived tables) *must* have a name. This is done by specifying an alias:

   ```
   SELECT x.SomeColumn
   FROM
   (
       SELECT SomeColumn
       FROM Users
   ) x
   ```

Answer (score 5):

`x` is an Alias for the table `Users`.

[Using Table Aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> The readability of a SELECT statement can be improved by giving a
>   table an alias, also known as a correlation name or range variable. A
>   table alias can be assigned either with or without the AS keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM Users x

SELECT * FROM Users AS x
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and link.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an alias for Users, which can be used in the query.

Imagine :

you want to retrieve datas from 2 tables, with an Id column in both

if you wanna retrieve these Ids, you have to prefix the column name to avoid confusion.

With alias:

```
select t1.Id, t2.Id
from mytableWithAReallyComplicatedName t1
inner join mySecondtableWithAReallyComplicatedName t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Without alias

```
select mytableWithAReallyComplicatedName.Id, mySecondtableWithAReallyComplicatedName.Id
from mytableWithAReallyComplicatedName 
inner join mySecondtableWithAReallyComplicatedName on mytableWithAReallyComplicatedName.Id = mySecondtableWithAReallyComplicatedName .Id
```

It the table names are long, the query might be fast less practical to read, with the second version.